# How to sync usernames/passwords between Mac Firefox & iPad Safari?

Tags: ipad, data-synchronization, safari, password, firefox

I use Firefox on my Mac and have hundreds of website passwords saved in its password store. I don't even remember my passwords half the time for the various sites that I use. How can I sync the usernames/passwords between the two devices? I'd also like to be able to sync my bookmarks if possible. I use Firefox Sync to keep my various computers in sync, but of course this will not work with the iPad.

Answer (score 5):

For passwords, I highly recommend [1Password](http://agilewebsolutions.com/products/1Password).

It will enter the passwords into Safari for iPad and it will sync your passwords with your Mac (if you setup the sync), and then you can search for what you need on the iPad.

Comment: A great suggestion. 1Password can utilize DropBox if you have it installed to keep a 2nd or 3rd or nth Macintosh update with your passwords and secure information. AND, if you have an iPhone/iPad, there are iPhone/iPad clients which also sync over DropBox so you can really have 1 secure place for passwords/information which is accessed via all of your devices (supports Windows and Linux too, but no here would care about those platforms :)

Comment: I second this.  1Password is likely one of the most useful applications I've run across in recent years.

Answer (score 2):

You can synchronize your Firefox bookmarks with your iPad using iTunes:

http://www.softsailor.com/how-to/47239-how-to-sync-firefox-internet-explorer-safari-bookmarks-with-your-ipad-iphone.html

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like this only works on Windows; on the mac, iTunes only gives the option to sync with Safari!

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody else mentioned it, I'll suggest [LastPass](http://lastpass.com/) -- it's another password manager very similar to 1Password. Lastpass acquired Xmarks (a bookmark synchronizing engine for all four major browsers) and you can get a [LastPass + Xmarks bundle](https://lastpass.com/features_joinpremiumxmarks.php) to sync both your passwords and bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

[Firefox Home](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/firefox-home/id380366933?mt=8) is intended to sync as much data from Mac Firefox to the iPad as possible. If that's not enough, you'll need a desktop program to get firefox syncing data to Safari and then through MobileMe or USB to the iPad.

I'd go with 1Password for passwords and Firefox Home for the rest.

Answer (score -1):

If you create a Firefox account, you can sync your bookmarks and passwords across all devices. I created an account so I could access all my bookmarks and password across an android, iOS, windows, and Mac devices. It works brilliantly to sync everything and back up your information.

Comment: And how will this work with Safari on an iPad (as the question asks)?